# google cloud logging from different provider's vm not working

Tags: logging, service, google-cloud-logging, gpc

Does GCP logging service  support other providers if not aws.
I'm trying to access from different cloud provider(not aws/azure), even if I try logging from my pc, its not receiving any. I followed this guides

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#joint-install

and
verified firewall as in
curl -sSL 'https://logging.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2' | head
that returns api config info.
Not sure if it will work with 3rd party providers or not (no mention about it in the doc)

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation that you posted, it is mentioned:

[Installing the Cloud Logging agent on a single
VM](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#joint-install)

> To install the agent, **ensure that you have the following**:
>
> 1.A supported VM instance in a **Google Cloud project or Amazon Web Services (AWS) account.**
>
> 2.Also ensure your VM is running a supported operating system.
>
> 3.A Stackdriver Workspace monitoring the AWS account containing the VM instance.

Therefore the documentation specifies only Google Cloud project or Amazon Web Services (AWS) account.